# PHP | MAMP connection problem with database

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I have a problem with MAMP, when I try to go on a web page connected with my database, I have a connection problem and the following message appears :

> Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use your DB details correctly Like this.

```
define("host", "localhost");
define("user", "root");
define("pwd", "your root password if exists or leave it blank");
define("db", "your db name");

$con1 = mysqli_connect(host, user, pwd, db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to Database!";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it fails to connect to Database

Comment: Can you show the codes that you are using?